# Confluent 3.3 unable to connect to schema-registry locally with kafka-avro-console-producer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Doing a simple experiment at command line after downloading confluent open source 3.3:

confluent start - which bring up all services without any visible errors:

```
confluent-3.3.0%   confluent start
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
```

Send a message with avro console producer, and see the connection error to localhost:8081, default schema-registry port:

```
confluent-3.3.0%   bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'
{"f1": "value1"}
[2018-06-28 12:22:47,827] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService:156)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The above is from the confluent platform docs https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.0/quickstart.html.  Any ideas for what other configuration might be needed to successfully connect to schema-registry appreciated.

Comment: Note: You may want to upgrade to patch release 3.3.1 for bugfixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting what worked for me, as I have seen many other unanswered questions with similar issue - restarting my laptop is sadly what did the trick.

On the mac, you can use Network Utility --> Port Scan to verify whether or not anything is running on the default `schema-registry` port `8081`.

It show up as `sunproxyadmin`.

Before the restart nothing was showing up for that port, even though `confluent status` was reporting schema-registry as 'UP' at times.